# selecta gallery with one or more images

Tags: sql

I have a problem with SQL sentence. I have entity Gallery which belongs to one Category (entity). Then I have entity GalleryImages and there are stored images for particular gallery. Gallery can have a lot of images, but gallery can also exists without images (no images are added yet).

Now I want to build SQL query to select (DESC) Gallery which has one or more images and belongs to some category.

Category (id, name)

Gallery (id, name, category_id)

GalleryImages (id, gallery_id, path)

Category -> Gallery (one to many)
Gallery -> GalleryImages (one to many)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Gallery as G
WHERE 
    G.category_id = 1
    AND G.id in (SELECT gallery_id FROM GalleryImages )
```

Replace 1 with caregory_id you want to select.

Comment: I tried this, but this query selects latest gallery no matter if gallery has images or not: 'SELECT p FROM NewsAdminBundle:Gallery p WHERE p.category_id = :category AND p.id IN (SELECT i FROM NewsAdminBundle:GalleryImages i) ORDER BY p.created_at DESC'

Answer (score 0):

Hmm -  looks like the basic question has already been answered.  But your setup bugs me slightly...
I think I'd restructure your tables a little bit (Assuming internationalization is not an issue).  Among other things, I don't feel there's a fundamental difference between the concepts of 'Category' and 'Gallery'.  Now, there may be 'super' and 'sub' categories/galleries, and images may belong to more than one at once (ie, from the Renniasance, by Michaelangelo, sculpture, etc).  It's similar to the concept of tags.

I'd probably revise your tables to something like:

```
Gallery (or Category, if you prefer)
=============
id  -- autoincrement
name  -- varchar(50) or something, unique
parent  -- fk reference to another Gallery.id row, optional

Image 
==========
id  -- autoincrement
name  -- varchar(50) or similar, non-unique
path  -- store as URI/URL, unique
description  -- varchar(128) or similar

Gallery_Image
===============
galleryId  -- fk reference to Gallery.id
imageId  -- fk reference to Image.id
         -- the pair is unique

Related_Gallery  -- optional table
================
galleryId  -- fk reference to Gallery.id
relationship  -- code, or fk reference to other table
relatedId  -- fk reference to Gallery.id
           -- entire row should be unique
           -- somewhat tricky to use.
```

Comment: Thanks for reply in tip. I forgot to mention that I also have a News entity and article in that entity belongs to category. Gallery also belongs to this category (ie. science, culture ...). So I have Categories and so as News as Galleries belongs to that categories.

Comment: @repincln - Then yes, they might be different entities (depends on how you conceptualize it).  However, keep in mind that a news entity may belong to multiple different categories.  The technique shown here for galleries should be applicable for your news categories.